# Closing the write-end of a pipe doesn't send an EOF to the other process

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork, exec

I'm trying to implement a minishell which must be able to pipe commands.

Initially, I was executing the processes sequentially, that is, I was waiting for `n`th a process to terminate before starting the `n + 1`th process (this is a minimal reproducible example which executes `ls | wc -l`):

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pid_t   family[2];
int     pipefd[2];
extern char **environ;

void    ft_exec(int i)
{
    char **ls = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    ls[0] = "/bin/ls";
    ls[1] = NULL;

    char **wc = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);
    wc[0] = "/usr/bin/wc";
    wc[1] = "-l";
    wc[2] = NULL;

    printf("ENTERED BY %d\n", getpid());
    if (i == 0)
    {
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        execve(ls[0], ls, environ);
    }
    if (i == 1)
    {
        dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
        execve(wc[0], wc, environ);
    }
}

void    ft_interpret(void)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 2)
    {
        family[i] = fork();
        printf("CREATED %d INSIDE %d\n", family[i], getpid());
        if (family[i] == 0)
            ft_exec(i);
        waitpid(family[i], NULL, 0);
        printf("TERMINATED %d IN %d\n", family[i], getpid());
        if (i == 0)
        {
            printf("CLOSED W%d\n", pipefd[1]);
            close(pipefd[1]);
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
            printf("CLOSED R%d\n", pipefd[0]);
            close(pipefd[0]);
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    pipe(pipefd);
    printf("PARENT ID IS %d\n", getpid());
    printf("CREATED PIPE WITH FDS R%d AND W%d\n", pipefd[0], pipefd[1]);
    ft_interpret();
}
```

However, I realized that this is not how the shell works, and in case if a command like `cat /dev/urandom | head -c 100` is given, the program will be stuck in a deadlock.

So I decided to fork the processes first, then whichever one of them exits, I close the associated write-ends of pipes.

For some reason, the reading command (`wc` in this case; if we change arguments to non-reading command, such as `printenv`, it'll execute correctly) gets stuck on reading, even though the main process has closed the write-end of the pipe and must've sent an EOF to `wc`.

Here's the modified code:

```c
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pid_t   family[2];
int     pipefd[2];
extern char **environ;

void    ft_exec(int i)
{
    char **ls = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 2);
    ls[0] = "/bin/ls";
    ls[1] = NULL;

    char **wc = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);
    wc[0] = "/usr/bin/wc";
    wc[1] = "-l";
    wc[2] = NULL;

    printf("ENTERED BY %d\n", getpid());
    if (i == 0)
    {
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        execve(ls[0], ls, environ);
    }
    if (i == 1)
    {
        dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
        execve(wc[0], wc, environ);
    }
}

void    ft_block_main_process(void)
{
    int     i;
    pid_t   terminated;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 2)
    {
        terminated = waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
        printf("TERMINATED %d IN %d\n", terminated, getpid());
        if (terminated == family[0])
        {
            printf("CLOSED W%d\n", pipefd[1]);
            close(pipefd[1]);
        }
        else if (terminated == family[1])
        {
            printf("CLOSED R%d\n", pipefd[0]);
            close(pipefd[0]);
        }
        i++;
    }
}

void    ft_interpret(void)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < 2)
    {
        family[i] = fork();
        printf("CREATED %d INSIDE %d\n", family[i], getpid());
        if (family[i] == 0)
            ft_exec(i);
        i++;
    }
    ft_block_main_process();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;

    pipe(pipefd);
    printf("PARENT ID IS %d\n", getpid());
    printf("CREATED PIPE WITH FDS R%d AND W%d\n", pipefd[0], pipefd[1]);
    ft_interpret();
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: You cannot "send an EOF".  An EOF is not a thing that ever appears on a pipe.  Once all the write ends of a pipe are closed, any reader that attempts to read from the pipe will not get data.  A `read` call will return a value that in some (many) languages is called "EOF".  But the EOF was not something that appeared (or was "sent to") the pipe.

Comment: Undoubtedly, you are leaving some write ends of the pipe open.  Go through your code and ensure that all ends are closed in the right place.

Comment: I suggest you try to simplify your code, or possibly start over from scratch with an empty `main` function. Then you one simple little bit, test it and make sure it works. Once it build without warnings (with verbose extra warning enabled) and goes through all tests, then you continue with the next little and simple bit. And don't use a loop or too generic functions. That will simplify quite a bit by itself, and also make it easier to test each bit separately.

Comment: You never close the write side of the pipe before you `exec` wc, so `wc` is waiting for that pipe to close.  It's blocked on itself.

Comment: The standard boiler plate for `dup2` includes a close.  It should almost always be `dup2(a, b); close(a)`  (You can do `close(b); dup2(a,b); close(a);`, but the initial close is not necessary)

Comment: You probably aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child and/or parent process.

**Rule of thumb**: If you
[`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)
one end of a pipe to standard input or standard output, close both of the
original file descriptors returned by
[`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)
as soon as possible.
In particular, you should close them before using any of the
[`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html)
family of functions.

Comment: Note that the reader on a pipe will not be notified of EOF until there are zero possible writers.  If the reader has the write end of the pipe open, the reader will never get EOF.  If the top-level shell has the write end of the pipe open, the reader will never get EOF.

Comment: thank you for the comments, I resolved my issue, please correct me if I'm mistaken in my explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the insightful comments.

If I add `close(pipefd[0])` and `close(pipefd[1])` immediately after `dup2()`s, the issue gets solved.

I thought that it was enough to close the pipe only from the main, shell process, but it turned out that all occurrences of fds have to be closed, including the ones inside children who inherit a copy.

The reason I got confused is the fact that the first piece of code worked. Now I realize that there, I was waiting for the first (`ls`) process to exit, so when it exits, its copy of the write-end gets destroyed, and I close the last copy of it in the main process. Then `wc` doesn't inherit any.

So now in my shell, during execution inside a child, after `dup2()`ing the descriptors, I close each and every descriptor created by `pipe()`, and it works.